# how to download images using google earth engine's python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am using Google's Earth Engine API to access LandSat images. 
The program is as given below,

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
```

**Load a landsat image and select three bands.**

```
landsat = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA
/LC81230322014135LGN00').select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);
```

**Create a geometry representing an export region.**

```
geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([116.2621, 39.8412, 116.4849, 40.01236]);
```

**Export the image, specifying scale and region.**

```
 export.image.toDrive({
    image: landsat,
    description: 'imageToDriveExample',
    scale: 30,  
    region: geometry
    });
```

it throws the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e6.py", line 11, in <module>
export.image.toDrive({
NameError: name 'export' is not defined
```

Please Help. I am unable to find the right function to download images.

Comment: please don't add big large fonts.. Also edit your code format...

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the python API, you have to use the 'batch' submodule. The default behaviour is to save to your google drive. You can specify your bounding box as a list of coordinates as well:

```
llx = 116.2621
lly = 39.8412
urx = 116.4849
ury = 40.01236
geometry = [[llx,lly], [llx,ury], [urx,ury], [urx,lly]]

task_config = {
    'description': 'imageToDriveExample',
    'scale': 30,  
    'region': geometry
    }

task = ee.batch.Export.image(landsat, 'exportExample', task_config)

task.start()
```

This should generate a file called 'exportExample.tif' in your GoogleDrive top folder.

Also note that the semicolons at the end of each line are not necessary in python.

Comment: How to select a folder of your drive?

Comment: Use the 'folder' keyword in the task_config dict

Comment: Using this now returns `TypeError: toDrive() got multiple values for argument 'description'` - can be fixed by removing `description` from `task_config`

Answer (score 2):

To build on [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41289973/8044684), you can also use:

```
geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([116.2621, 39.8412, 116.4849, 40.01236])
```

from your original post, but add the following line beneath it so the coordinates are in the correct format for the *task_config-->Region* field:

```
geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([116.2621, 39.8412, 116.4849, 40.01236])
geometry = geometry['coordinates'][0]
```

It prevents a "task_config" formatting mismatch when you get to here:

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image(landsat, 'exportExample', task_config)
```

This will allow you to use the given function from the API, but it will extract the coordinates in such a way that you can use them in the approach suggested by Ben above.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code, `Export` should start from the capital letter. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting).

Answer (score 0):

Where do you specify the dates? Is there any good, quick, documentation or tutorial for Python? seems there are plenty about JavaScript one!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution that worked for me i.e. downloading to a local drive directly**

This assumes you have already been able to access and select a multiband image. More information can be found at [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl)

Also note, you can change the 'scale' to 10m but that will cause the image size to increase and Google may not allow you to download beyond 50mb.

```
region = aoi.geometry()

# Multi-band GeoTIFF file.
url = img.getDownloadUrl({
    'bands': [
    "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B8A", "B9", 
    "B11", "B12", "AOT", "MSK_CLDPRB" ],
    'region': region,
    'scale': 30,
    'format': 'GEO_TIFF'
})
response = requests.get(url)
with open('multi_band_file.tif', 'wb') as fd:
  fd.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is good, quick example of python api.You can check this [link](https://gee-python.blogspot.com). There is 1 post for download satellite image using python api.

Comment: It may not be a good answer when the link breaks, but for now I found it quite useful, especially for how to download to local drive instead of google drive.