# How to get the download urls for an image collection from Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, image, google-earth-engine

I am still relatively new to Google Earth Engine, but had a question about getting the download URLs for each image in an Image Collection. The question is exactly that, how do I obtain the set of download urls for each image in an imagery collection--given that I have pared each image down to a reasonable size.

Note, I did look through Stackoverflow and found an existing question about downloading a single image to a google Drive, but this question does not provide any information about image collections.

[how to download images using google earth engine's python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219705/how-to-download-images-using-google-earth-engines-python-api)

The following bit of code will generate some small image patches of Landsat 8 imagery. Each patch is only a handful of kb in size.

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1').select('B8')
col.filterDate('1/1/2015', '1/30/2015')
boundary_region = ee.Geometry.Point([-2.40986111110000012, 26.76033333330000019]).buffer(300)
col.filterBounds(boundary_region)

def clipper(image):
    return image.clip(region)

col.map(clipper)
```

Now I would like to download each image in the collection `col`.

Earth Engine provides a couple of ways to iterate over imagery collections: the `map()` and `iterate()` functions, but apparently both of those functions do not work for the download functions.

Now it seems like once I can generate the url for a single image using the function:

```
boundary_geojson = ee.Geometry.Polygon(boundary_region.bounds().getInfo().coordinates[0]).toGeoJSONString()

def downloader(image): 
    url = ee.data.makeDownloadUrl(
        ee.data.getDownloadId({
            'image': image.serialize(),
            'scale': 30,
            'filePerBand': 'false',
            'name': 'test',
            'region': boundary_geojson,
        }))
    return url
```

*Note, for some reason I can't seem to get the `boundary_geojson` variable to work properly.*

now the set of urls should be a call as simple as

```
col.map(downloader)
```

but that does not work.

Does anyone know how to generate the list of urls the correspond to the images in an image collection?

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943061/how-to-iterate-over-and-download-each-image-in-an-image-collection-from-the-goog/46961005#46961005) solves your map() issue.

Comment: I try your downloader function and it works!